# Strange behavior of for cycle(seq) in R

Tags: r, for-loop, cycle

I have this code:

```
for(b in seq(nrow(A), 1, -1)){
result[nrow(A)-b+1]<-A[b,ncol(A)]/A[b,b]
for(t in seq(b,(nrow(A)-1), 1)){
  result[nrow(A)-b+1]<- result[nrow(A)-b+1]-(result[t,b]/A[b,b])
```

and getting this error`Error in seq.default(b, (nrow(A) - 1), 1) : wrong sign in 'by' argument`
My idea is, that second cycle in first step of first cycle doesnt run, in second step once, in third step twice...
What is wrong? It thinks maybe I wrote it bad, because in first step i have "start number" bigger by one then "end number" and with the sign of "by number" this cycle can not reach the end number.
But I need it in this way, i assumed that it in that case it just jump over that cycle...
I know I can do it with some condition before cycle, but I want to know core of the problem.
Thank you very much,
Martin!
Whole code:

```
Gaus<-function(A){
for(i in seq(1, nrow(A)-1, 1)){
for(n in seq(i, nrow(A)-1, 1)){
  multiplier<-A[n+1,i]/A[i,i]
  if(multiplier!=0)
    for(ch in seq(i, ncol(A), 1)){
      print(ch)
      A[n+1,ch]<-A[n+1,ch]-(A[i,ch]*multiplier)
      print(A)

    }
}
```

}

```
 result <-c()
for(b in seq(nrow(A), 1, -1)){
result[nrow(A)-b+1]<-A[b,ncol(A)]/A[b,b]
for(t in b:(nrow(A)-1)){
  result[nrow(A)-b+1]<- result[nrow(A)-b+1]-(result[t,b]/A[b,b])
}
```

}
}

```
A <- matrix(c(2,4,5,8,3,2,8,7,9,1,6,5), 3, 4, TRUE)
Gaus(A)`
```

Comment: Please show some example and expected output based on that.

Comment: A <- matrix(c(2,4,5,8,3,2,8,7,9,1,6,5), 3, 4, TRUE)

Comment: `seq` returns this error if `to` is larger than `from` and `by` is negative, or the other way around: `seq(0, 1, -1); seq(0, -1, 1)`. Find out why that happens in your code.

Comment: i changed it to     for(t in b:(nrow(A)-1)) but now it says Error in result[t, b] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: `result` is undefined and the closing brace brackets are missing and there may be other problems too but those prevent the code from being run even if one uses the `A` in your comment.  Please provide complete self-contained code with no syntax errors when asking questions on SO.    http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: On the first pass through the outer loop `b` will be more than `nrow(A)-1` and the "direction" implied will not match the increment in the second call to `seq`. I think the body of your question is saying that you expect the `seq` function to automagically correct your errors in logic. The strangeness I fear is not in `seq` but in your mind.

Comment: Try this code, and you will see what is the problem with for cycle... if n is 5, so then i become 5 and condition is to 4(I expect, it will just skip then) then it print(k) anyway......                                                                            for(n in seq(5, 1, -1)){
  print(n)
for(i in n:4){
  print("k")
  print(n)
}
}